# FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK doesn't work on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, android-activity, launch, android-4.4-kitkat

My app will pop up a splash screen to tell user after user logged in, which is implemented with an `Activity`.

It takes some time for app to communicate with backend server, and user might press "Home" button to temporarily leave the app during logging in.

I don't want my splash screen to interrupt the user if the user returned to the home screen. So I start the splash screen activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` flag, so it won't be brought to front when it is launched.

The code works fine until 4.4 KitKat. On Android 4.4, even if I set the flag on the `Intent` that starts the `Activity`, the splash screen still jump to front when the app is in the background.

Any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems not related to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.

In Android 4.3, `Activity` started from inactive `Activity` is also inactive.
But in Android 4.4, `Activity` started form inactive `Activity` will be brought to front.

So I added a bunch of code to resolve the issue:

I add a `isPaused` property to `BaseAcitity`, which is the base class of all activities in my app.

```java
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String START_FROM_PAUSED_ACTIVITY_FLAG = "START_FROM_PAUSED_ACTIVITY_FLAG";

    protected boolean paused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        paused = true;
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }
}
```

Then when I start the start the `SplashActivity`, I'll put the `isPaused` value into the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SplashActivity.class);

boolean isStartingFromBackgroundActivity = activity.isPaused();
intent.putExtra(BaseActivity.START_FROM_PAUSED_ACTIVITY_FLAG, isStartingFromBackgroundActivity);

startActivity(intent);
```

And check isPaused value in `onCreate` callback in `SplashAcitivity`, and push the `SplashAcitivty` to background if the value is true.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isStartedFromBackgroundActivity())
        moveTaskToBack(true);

}

private boolean isStartedFromBackgroundActivity() {
    return getIntent().getBooleanExtra(START_FROM_PAUSED_ACTIVITY_FLAG, false);
}
```